How can I use different IBus engines on different keyboard concurrently?
I work with several languages and need to toggle entry between different alphabets, for which I use dedicated keyboards. I can easily set up persistent layouts on each dedicated keyboard using setxkbmap -device NN -layout xx, where NN is the device id as obtained with xinput --list, and "xx" is the two-letter language code.
One of the languages I use cannot be entered with XKB. I can switch to it from the command line using ibus engine 'engine', and change back with the same command but specifying a different engine.
Unfortunately, the ibus engine method changes the behaviour on all keyboards and overrides xkb, and I haven't been able to find an ibus keyboard-specific switch like for "setxkbmap".
Any help on how I can set concurrently two separate keyboards, each with a different IBUS engine, is greatly appreciated.
I am using Mate on top of Ubuntu 22.04.
Some older relevant posts are this one about different layouts for different keyboards with xkb, and with ibus
